# Create public alias for a type in C# library/dll

Tags: c#

I have a C# library and want to define some alias for enums and classes which accessible when using the library. For example, alias name "Class2" for Class1" or alias "Color2" for "Color1". I tried
"using Class2 = Class1;" in the library and it's recognized in the library but it's not accessible when using the library in web application.

Comment: Using aliases are only valid for a single file at a time; beyond that: what you want is not defined in c#

Comment: In c#, aliases are a compile-time concept. If you reflect the assembly you'll find that your code actually uses the original type names. So the idea of exposing them in an assembly is a non-starter Not possible.

Comment: @MickyD In c++ you have header files that you #include. Header files are source code and can define aliases. When you set a reference in c#, you aren't accessing source code but compiled code, and any sort of aliases are not contained in there .